# Adding values from a different table based on values in multiple columns of another table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 Tables

```
Table 1
Name    column2 column3 column 4
Suzy    English  null     null  
Rocky   Polish   Irish  null
John    English  American  Funny 
George  Funny   English   null

Table 2
Column    Value 
English    2     
Polish    3     
Irish     2      
Funny     0  
American   1
```

The values in Column in Table 2 are unique.
I want to add a column in Table 1 which finds all the matching values from columns 2, 3 and 4 in table 1, finds the corresponding values in the ‘column’ in table 2 and the adds the corresponding values, So that Table 1 now is updated to look like

```
Table 1
Name    column2 column3 column 4    Total
Suzy    english  null     null      2
Rocky   Polish   Irish  null        5
John    English  American  Funny    3
George  Funny   English  null       2
```

Is this possible at all? Or do I need to have another query first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structures are less than ideal, since apparently all of `column2`, `column3` and `column4` in table 1 contain items of the same "type".

There are various ways of creating your totals - we can either perform multiple joins or use a correlated subquery. I'm using the subquery here:

```
select
    *,
    (select SUM(t2.Value) from Table2 t2
    where t2.Column1 in (t1.Column2,t1.Column3,t1.Column4)) as TotalValue
from
    Table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks Damien, that was just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join and do addition as below

```
select t1.*, [Total] = isnull(C2.Value,0) + isnull(C3.Value,0) + isnull(C4.Value,0) 
   from [Table 1] t1
   left join [Table 2] c2 on t1.Column1 = c2.[Column]
   left join [Table 2] c3 on t1.Column1 = c3.[Column]
   left join [Table 2] c4 on t1.Column1 = c4.[Column]
```

Comment: Need to use a `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` to wrap individual values in that addition - otherwise `NULL`s can propagate and many `Total`s will be `NULL`.